# Proof binomial coefficient

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove the following:
$$\binom{n + p}{k} = \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \cdot \binom{p}{k - j}$$
How do I do it? Induction?
And can someone hint me at how to start?

Comment: Consider the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^{n+p}$ as well as in $(1+x)^n(1+x)^p$.

Comment: Several proofs here: [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In totaly, you have $n+p$ items, you keep $n$ items in box 1 and keep $p$ items in box 2.

You have to pick a total of $k$ items.

If you pick $j$ items from box 1, you have to pick $k-j$ items from box 2 to make it up.